# jQuery Mobile Fixed Header and Footer scroll at the first moment. (Bug?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, header, footer, css-position

My question is about `JQM`. I'm currently developing an mobile app, which includes a fixed Header and Footer.
On `Safari` and `Chrome (Mac)` everything works fine, but when i view the app on the `iPhone` or `iPad Safari`, the fixed Header and Footer doesn't stay on top at the first moment. After scrolling and stopping, the header and footer stay fixed, as they should.

My source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" />
        <script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
            });
        </script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="master">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="header-custom">
                <img src="images/logo.png" style="height: 44px;"> <a href="index.html" data-icon="refresh" id="refreshButton" class="ui-btn-right" style="fmargin-top: 4px;" data-iconpos="notext">Aktualisieren</a>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="rssListView"></ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

The custom header class:

```css
/* Custom navbar */
.header-custom {
    height: 44px;
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Posted css and html doesn't relate to your issue. Can you plz post the respective code, css and js?

Comment: Which part do you mean? The other stuff is just the standard construct of JQM. I will update my post. -> I found a "fix" for this, but i'm not very happy with it. If i scroll the window 1px, the header refreshes and works perfectly. $(document).scrollTop(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. If i add a `<h1></h1>` Element to my header it works fine, but i'm not sure why JQM does that stuff. Is this a bug in JQM?